# Java Sort with Comparable

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, comparable

I have an `ArrayList` of `Person` objects. A `Person` has `name`, `age` and `height`. My goal is to sort this `ArrayList<Person>`. I have implemented `Comparable<Person>` and have defined `compareTo()` but when I try to sort it, it give me this error:

> The method sort(Comparator) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the argument ()"

The way I understand is that if you implement Comparable and then define `compareTo` everything else is magically done for you.

Can some one explain how to this works and why I am getting this error?

Comment: What `Comparator` are you passing? Can you please share some code?

Comment: use `Collections.sort` instead. ArrayList itself does not know how to sort without a Comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use a structure which uses the `Comparable` interface to order its elements when you add a new element inside it :

```
TreeSet<Person> persons = new TreeSet<>();
Person personOne = ...
Person personTwo = ...
persons.add(personOne);
persons.add(personTwo);
```

Either you use a `List` and the `Collections.sort(List<T> list)` method which takes as argument the list you want to sort (there is an  overload of this method but it is not relevant in your case):

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
Person personOne = ...
Person personTwo = ...
persons.add(personOne);
persons.add(personTwo);
Collections.sort(persons);
```

With the `TreeSet`, the elements are sorted as soon as added and with the `List`, the elements are not sorted when you add them.
 Only, the call to the `Collections.sort()` method sorts the list.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that your code looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = ...;
people.sort();
```

Look at the JavaDoc for `ArrayList`. Do you see a method `public void sort()` (with no parameters)? **No** - there is no such method.

That is the meaning of the error: `The method sort(Comparator) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the argument ()` -- There is a method `sort(Comparator)`, but you have not supplied parameters that match it.

Assuming `Person` implements `Comparable` (and therefore has a `compareTo()` method), you can use `Collections.sort()`, which sorts arbitrary `List<Comparable>`

```
Collections.sort(people);
```

This is because `Collections` has a static method:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list);
```

(it also has a `sort(List<T> list, Comparator<T> comparator)`)

... or you can pass a comparator to `List.sort()`, which is quite easy with Java 8 lambdas:

```
people.sort((a,b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

(Or, if you prefer the old style):

```
people.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
});
```

(Actually as of Java 8, this comparator is provided by the standard library, as `Comparator.naturalOrder()`)

The point of comparators is that you can sort according to different criteria. For example:

```
people.sort((a,b) -> a.lastName().compareTo(b.lastName()));
people.sort((a,b) -> a.lastName().compareToIgnoreCase(b.lastName()));
people.sort((a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.age(),b.age()));
// etc.
```

... or using methods in `Comparator`:

```
people.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::lastName));
people.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::lastName)
        .thenComparing(Person::firstName));
```

Comment: Why write `(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)` when you can write `Comparator.naturalOrder()`?

Comment: You can also pass `null` as a comparator, which will work the same as a natural order comparator.